# arithmetic equalities drawn from power series

Tags: induction, power-series, arithmetic

$$-\ln(1-x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$$

$$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$

When I work out the power series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty c_nx^n$ of $(\ln(1-x))^2$ using the Cauchy product of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$ and itself, I get $c_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}\frac{1}{n-k}$.

If I work out the Cauchy product of the power series of $-\ln(1-x)$ and $\frac{1}{1-x}$ and integrate it, I conclude that $c_n=\frac{2}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}$.

I would like a more basic proof that $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}\frac{1}{n-k} = \frac{2}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}$.

I failed at induction as well as trying to use the symmetry of the added terms.

Comment: Write each term $\frac{1}{k}\frac{1}{n-k}=\frac{1/n}{k}+\frac{1/n}{n-k}$.

Comment: If you code something as \Sigma_{k=1}^n then you see $$\Sigma_{k=1}^n,$$ but if the code is \sum_{k=1}^n then you see $$\sum_{k=1}^n.$$ The latter is standard; hence my edits to the question.

Comment: You were right to do so, thanks, I had tried Displaystyle which didn't do the job either. Now I know !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quite elementary way to show it is as follows:

First note that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}\frac{1}{n-k} = \frac{2}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k} \Leftrightarrow n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}\frac{1}{n-k} =2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k} $$

Now, you may prove the equality on the right:

\begin{eqnarray*} n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k(n-k)}
& = & \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{n}{k(n-k)} \\
& = & \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{n-k+k}{k(n-k)} \\
& = & \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left( \frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{n-k}\right) \\
& = & \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k} + \underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n-k}}_{= \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}} \\
& = & 2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}
\end{eqnarray*}